# Chart helper theme XML spec?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mschart

Is there an authoritative description of all that's possible with Chart theming in the MVC Chart helper?  I've seen a half dozen tutorials but nothing like an MSDN style complete reference.  Does this exist?

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for a couple of days for information on this, I don't believe there is a schema available, but there is a full reference on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx

Fortunately, you can create a chart using code, and then serialize it to XML - this will produce output which can be used directly in your theme.xml file or string.

Here is an example pie chart with a few properties set:

```
Chart Chart1 = new Chart();

double[] yValues = { 71.15, 23.19, 5.66 };
string[] xValues = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" };

Chart1.Series.Add(new Series("Default"));
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points[0].Color = Color.MediumSeaGreen;
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points[1].Color = Color.PaleGreen;
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points[2].Color = Color.LawnGreen;
Chart1.Series["Default"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
Chart1.Series["Default"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";

Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("ChartArea1"));
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

Chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend());
Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
```

and then the relevant code to serialize it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb)) {
    Chart1.Serializer.Content = SerializationContents.Default;
    Chart1.Serializer.Save(writer);
}
```